# Grid Virtual Scrolling with Grouping Records

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

currently i am working on JqGrid which support virtual scrolling but when ever i group the records the virtual scrolling automatically convert in to paging options while the virtual scrolling option is enabled in JqGrid.

i have searched many other grids but not able to find any grid which support both virtual scrolling and grouping together.

Now i want to know why this not possible? Can any one explain why virtual scrolling and grouping can not work together? i am not able to find any reason yet.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation contains ["Limitations"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping#limitations) section which contains the requirement `scroll: false` (no virtual scrolling). Such requirement is really important for the current implementation of grouping and virtual scrolling. So you can't combine both features in one grid.